# Cant bind the table to DropdownList

Tags: asp.net

I have a table with two columns  named StudentId and name and I am trying to bind the name column to a dropdownlist control which works using the code below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(!Page.IsPostBack)
          fillStudentName();
    }

    void fillStudentName() {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;database=Projects;UID=sa;Password=1234");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from StudentInfo", con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);

        ddlstudent.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlstudent.DataTextField = "Name";

        ddlstudent.DataBind();

    }
```

The problem is when I add this line into code.

```
 //    ddlstudent.DataValueField = "StudentId";->>this part throws exception
```

I am getting this exception below.

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'StudentId'.

But this field exists and I have double checked the name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... does not contain a property with the name 'StudentId'

The error is self-explanatory, you have forgotten to select this field. So change the sql query from:

```
select Name from StudentInfo
```

to

```
select Name, StudentId from StudentInfo
```

As an aside, the method name `fillStudentName` is outdated. It should be renamed to `DataBindDdlStudent` or something similar.